# Send Twillio SMS response to email using PHP

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to send twillio incoming/ received message to my email address automatically. Please help me regarding this.

I have tried to follow following doc but not able to find something usefull.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181788-Forwarding-SMS-Messages-to-your-Email-Inbox

Comment: Show your source code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I already mentioned I am not sure where to start. I just want a reference doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a webhook for this purpose. Whenever you will receive an SMS. Twilio will post details on this URL you have created and then you can parse this and write a script to send mail.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-webhook

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181788-Forwarding-SMS-Messages-to-your-Email-Inbox